# How can I replace the element at said index and return the old element?

Tags: java, list, replace, indexof

I have a function with 2 parameters. The first is the index of a list. the second is an element that is suppose to replace whatever element was in said index. The function returns the OLD element(that was replaced) not the new one.

```
public T replace( int index, T elem)
{
   if(index > size())
   {
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index out of bounds");
   }
   T old;
   old = list[index];

  list[index] = elem;
  return old;
}
```

Im returning the new element instead of the old. How do i change the element and return the old element?

Comment: *Im returning the new element instead of the old*: no, you don't. If you think you are, explain why by posting a complete minimal example with expected and actual output.

Comment: @JBNizet i think you already answered my question.